# Undefined variable: fonctions (View: D:\wamp\www\BTPl\resources\views\salarie\create.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

I'm a beginner in laravel, I have a form to add Salarie, in table Salaries there is a foreign key to table fonctions (belongsTo relation), I want to fill a select by fonction.

**SalarieController.php**

```
public function getFonctions(){
        $fonctions=Fonction::all();
        return view("salarie.create",compact("fonctions"));
    }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<select class="form-control" name="fonction_id">
                        <option></option>
                        @foreach($fonctions as $fonction)
                        <option>{{ $fonction->fonction }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                     </select>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/getfonctions','SalarieController@getFonctions');
```

Comment: from what i see it looks good, try `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` from `cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

**SalarieController.php**

```
public function getFonctions(Request $request){
        $fonctions = Fonction::get();
        return view("salarie.create",compact("fonctions"));
    }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
  @if(!empty($fonctions))
            @foreach($fonctions as $fonction)
            <option value="{{ $fonction->id }}">{{ $fonction->fonction}}</option>
            @endforeach
  @endif
```